# Comparing a list to a dictionary and printing message based on results

Tags: python

I hope I can explain this properly. I have a dictionary that has a list of names in it. I also have a list with another listing of names. What I want to do is to take the names in the list and pass them into the dictionary, if a name is mentioned in the list, but **NOT** in the dictionary I want it to print a message telling the person to take a survey. Here is what I have so far:

```
favorite_languages = {'Jen': 'python', 'Sarah': 'c', 'Edward': 'Ruby', 'Phil': 'python'}
poll_takers = ['Jen', 'Greg', 'Sarah', 'Allan', 'Bob']


for name, language in favorite_languages.items():
    print(name.title() + "'s favorite language is " + language.title() + ".")

    if name in favorite_languages:
        print('Thank you for taking the poll!')
    if name in poll_takers and not favorite_languages:
        print('Please take our poll!')
```

When I run this it prints the name of each person in the favorite_languages list, and it prints thank you after each one, but it won't find the missing names from the `poll_takers` list and printing the proper message.

I know this is fairly simple, but I've tried a couple things and can't get it. Does anyone know what I am missing?

Comment: @wim has provided you a nice hint, so as he is telling you, just use the set where you have the names of `poll_takers` and the keys of your `favorite_language`. I think I can provide an answer, but it seems like an assignment, so I will let you figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the issue:

```
for name, language in favorite_languages.items():
```

This only iterates over the results, i.e. those names who have already taken the poll.  So you'll need to somehow iterate over the `poll_takers` who don't have results yet as well.

Here's a hint:

```
>>> favorite_languages.keys() | poll_takers
{'Allan', 'Bob', 'Edward', 'Greg', 'Jen', 'Phil', 'Sarah'}
```

Comment: very precise your response. I like you didn't solve his homework, but your hint is enough to allow him to do it by himself.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you iterate through only the items in favorite_languages, so that the second if statement won't ever evaluate to True.

Instead, you can use a set() which takes only unique values from both the keys in favorite_languages and the values in poll_takers:

favorite_languages = {'Jen': 'python', 'Sarah': 'c', 'Edward': 'Ruby', 'Phil': 'python'}
poll_takers = ['Jen', 'Greg', 'Sarah', 'Allan', 'Bob']

```
for name in set(favorite_languages + poll_takers):
    try:
       language = favorite_languages[name]
    except KeyError:
       # This means the name isn't in your favorite_languages dictionary
       print('Please take our poll!')
       return

    print(name.title() + "'s favorite language is " + language.title() + ".")

    print('Thank you for taking the poll!')
```

Answer (score 0):

I would maybe approach this from the poll_takers end like this:

```
favorite_languages = {'Jen': 'python', 'Sarah': 'c', 'Edward': 'Ruby', 'Phil': 'python'}
poll_takers = ['Jen', 'Greg', 'Sarah', 'Allan', 'Bob']

for name in poll_takers:
    if name in favorite_languages.keys():
        print(name + "'s favorite language is " + favorite_languages[name] + ".")
        print("Thank you for taking the poll!")
    else:
        print(name + " does not have a favorite language.")
        print("Please take our poll!")
```